# Xamarin android Application not working in any Physical device

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I developed a xamarin android application that can perform few activities. I developed it with Xamarin and Visual studio 2015 Update 3. I always tested this application with my emulator and one of my device (Samsung tab 3 lite). I thought as it works in my physical device so it will also work in any physical device. thats why I installed it to another android phone, but i found that's it not working. it's showing "Unfortunately myapp has stoped working." Then i tested it other several devices like asus zenfone 5 , samsung tab 10" tab , LG nexus. My app is not running in any devices except my own device that i used to develop this application.

Error screen  after deployment. 
[image]

Comment: have you deployed also the Xamarin dependencies or any other third party library required by your application?

Comment: @blackibiza dear I deployed Xamarin Android Api-23 and Mono Shared Runtime with that app. But not required any other third party library .

Comment: you should attach a debugger to one of those device and see the logs

Comment: Could you try in release mode?

Comment: @Prabakaran not working :(

Comment: Please past the error log here

Comment: Didn't you see any info in output window in your visual studio after getting this exception in phone?

Comment: @Prabakaran Please have a look. http://pastebin.com/TUugQvAL

Dear , this app only opens in Emulator and Developer Unlocked Physical device that i used to develop this app. But not in other normal device

Comment: What is your Xamarin.Android app target framework version?

Comment: @Prabakaran minimum API level 16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the different possible solutions from the below Xamarin forum.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/10159/can-no-longer-run-android-applications-using-xamarin-4-2-and-xamarin-android-4-10-1

Most people confirmed that the below solution works for them.

> Setting `<AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>True</AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>`
>
> to
>
> `<AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>False</AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>`
>
> in Xamarin.Android project file.