# Trouble Locating <AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk>True</AndroidUseLatestPlatformSdk> in Xamarin.Android Project

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Can't find  in my Xamarin.Android project's .csproj file. Searched thoroughly and checked other properties. Facing issues running the app on physical devices ([Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40192699/xamarin-android-application-not-working-in-any-physical-device)). Need guidance on locating or modifying this setting. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can't find in my Xamarin.Android project's .csproj file.

Right click on your project -> click `Unload Project` :

[image]

Then you can see your .csproj file.

Comment: It worked but project got gone. And when i reloaded it, it got back;